# Ui datepicker from date and to date should be selected in the same month

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery Ui Date picker , i am struck with strange requirement given by client, help me in going forward.

In my scenario, i have two date pickers**(from,to Date)** ,now the requirement is i need to select only the past days only(done),and the second one is if i select the from date in one month and to date also should be in the same month only (eg: if i select from date in may month and in to month i have to select only in the may month only remaining has to disable).

fiddle:jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishna123/hFnf8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do that like so:

```
$("#from").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);

        var date = $("#from").datepicker('getDate');
        var d = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", d);

    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hFnf8/1/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo for Quick Response, but the above code is failing in one scenario in my particular condition.where the max date should not be greater than today's date , if i select july 1st(this month) in from date and i dont want to select to date greater than today i.e(to date should always be less than today)..

Comment: Not sure I get it, is this what you're trying to do -> http://jsfiddle.net/hFnf8/6/